# Method to query the package database in a case-insensitive manner?

Tags: dpkg

I have the name of a file and I need to determine what package provides it. If it weren't for the fact that I need to perform a case-insensitive search, the following command would work fine:

```
dpkg -S filename.txt
```

This works great if the file is named 'filename.txt' but not if it is named 'Filename.txt'.

Consulting the [manpage for the `dpkg` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dpkg) doesn't reveal anything about a case-insensitive option for the command and I'm left in the dark.

*Is* there a way to query the package database for a certain file in a case-insensitive manner?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dpkg` accepts wildcard patterns. That's ok if you don't know whether the file name has an initial capital letter, but it doesn't scale.

```
dpkg -S '[Ff][Ii][Ll][Ee][Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee].[Tt][Xx][Tt]'
```

With no extra tools, you can easily reproduce what `dpkg -S` does internally:

```
grep -Fi filename.txt /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list
```

You can use [dlocate](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dlocate) [image: Install dlocate] to speed up `dpkg -S` with an index (like `locate` speeds up `find /`, but you don't gain nearly as much with `dlocate`). Since `dlocate` is built on `locate`, it accepts the same options including `-i` for a case-insensitive search. Since `dlocate` uses an index (normally rebuilt every night), it might be slightly out of date.

```
dlocate -i filename.txt
```

[apt-file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/apt-file) [image: Install apt-file] searches a file name in all packages that are available for installations. It has a `-ui` option for a case-insensitive search.

```
apt-file -i search filename.txt
```

Comment: +1 for an accurate and comprehensive answer. Thank you! This was exactly the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: One quick question: does `dlocate` update the index when first installed? I will mostly be using the tool on a build farm where the command will likely run immediately after install.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison `update-dlocatedb` is called from the postinst, so yes.